# Repeated calls to Room Persistence Library truncates local file table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a android app with a local sqlite database that I access using Room Persistence Library.

I am able to access the file using this:

```
cAssetsDatabase cassetsDatabase  = Room.databaseBuilder(context, cAssetsDatabase.class, "localDB.sqlite").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();


cAssets cassets = cassetsDatabase.daoAccesscAssetsDB().fetchAssetByTagID(TagID);
```

Everything works correctly, unfortunately after leaving this activity and returning, trying to access the database returns null.

When I pull the database off the device after accessing it, it seems that the table I used the select on has been truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably notice two other files the same name as the database file but one suffixed with **-wal** and the other suffixed with **-shm**. Copy all three files.

This is because [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) (Write-ahead logging) (which is likely being used), writes changes to the WAL file rather than the database file and only applies them to the database file when the database is checkpointed, otherwise the changes are accessed from the -wal file (-shm is a shared memory file a log file for the -wal file).

Comment: I see the -wal file being created in the same directory as my database. I'm not sure what you mean by "Copy all three files"?